# Problem with a iteration of calculation of Cross Recurrence Plot

Tags: python, function, loops, iteration

I would like to ask You for a favor:

I have a data frame with a variable of Electrodermal activity (EDA) from different subjects (eda1, eda2, eda3,...). 
I manually calculate [Cross Recurrence Quantification Plot](http://www.pik-potsdam.de/~donges/pyunicorn/api/timeseries/cross_recurrence_plot.html) and Recurrence Rate for subjects as a measure of synchronization.

```
from pyunicorn.timeseries import CrossRecurrencePlot, RecurrencePlot
from nolitsa import data, dimension, delay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import pylab

eda1 = data['eda1raw'] 
eda2 = data['eda2raw']

eda1z = stats.zscore(eda1)
eda2z = stats.zscore(eda2)

DIM = 5  
TAU = 10  
METRIC = "supremum" 
THRESHOLD=0.5 
crp = CrossRecurrencePlot(eda1z, eda2z, dim=DIM, tau=TAU, metric=METRIC, normalize=False, threshold=THRESHOLD) 
print "Recurrence rate - RReda1vs2z:", crp.recurrence_rate()
```

But I need automatic function or iteration for the function of recurrence rate (abbreviation: RR) for all subjects (eda1raw1, eda1raw2,... eda1rawN).
I have many variables of EDA a I don´t  want to write:

```
crp = CrossRecurrencePlot(eda1z, eda2z, dim=DIM, tau=TAU, metric=METRIC, normalize=False, threshold=THRESHOLD) 
crp1 = CrossRecurrencePlot(eda3z, eda4z, dim=DIM, tau=TAU, metric=METRIC, normalize=False, threshold=THRESHOLD) 
...
```

The final result it should be the matrix of recurrence rate of EDA for all subjects:
[image]

I tried something:

```
automaticcal = [dataWithEda] 
for i in automaticcal: 
      CrossRecurrencePlot(i, i, dim=3, tau=10, metric="supremum", normalize=False, threshold=0.5)
print(CrossRecurrencePlot)
```

Then transpose to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Mikuláš Muroň:

```
# Save data to list
input_data = [xd, yd, cd, dd, ed, fd, gd, hd, iid, jd, kd, ld, md, nd, od, pd]
# transform to np.array
input_data_numpy_array = [np.array(x) for x in input_data]
# counting zscore
zscore_data = [stats.zscore(x) for x in input_data_numpy_array]
# counting phasic diemnsion of EDA
eda_data = [cvxEDA(x, delta=1) for x in zscore_data]

# processing data - actual and next element
for eda_data1,eda_data2 in zip(eda_data, eda_data[1:]):
    crp = CrossRecurrencePlot(eda_data1.next(), eda_data2.next(), dim=DIM, tau=TAU, metric=METRIC, normalize=False, threshold=THRESHOLD)
    pylab.imshow(crp.recurrence_matrix())
    pylab.xlabel("$n$")
    pylab.ylabel("$n$")
    pylab.show()

    print("Recurrence rate:", crp.recurrence_rate())
```